# How to detect the application/process that's using the camera?

Tags: windows-7, virus, camera

The light that near the camera on my laptop is lighting although I'm not using it. Seems it's a virus or an unknown application. How can I detect the application/process that's using the camera ?

Comment: That. Is. Creepy.

Comment: More information is required to help you.

Comment: @Ramhound: What kind of info you need?

Comment: What kind of camera do you have.  do you have the camera's software installed or just the drivers for it installed.

Comment: The camera is integrated with my laptop - HP pavilon. There is only its software from HP

Comment: @Homam - Is that software running when you see the light on the camera turned on. There has to be device information on the camera itself.

Comment: @r.tanner.f That's why some people cover up their integrated webcams with tape or a post-it note when not in use.

Comment: Yeah, that does sound strange. Would it be possible to directly rename the driver for the camera, or one of it's .dll files, then if a malware program is trying to access it, your system would return an error, hopefully giving you the name of the program attempting to access or run it?

Comment: Check this http://superuser.com/questions/335116/finding-out-which-app-is-using-the-webcam/338132#338132

Answer (score 0):

I just answered in linked question ( https://superuser.com/a/612272/233899 ):

Applications using "handles" to access various interfaces provided by OS. Device handles is actually "file handles".

Process Hacker ( http://processhacker.sf.net/ ) can search handles in all processes (Ctrl+F to open "Find handles and DLL's").

My webcam device handle was

\Device\USBPDO-6

I found that after comparing all \Device* handles opened by skype.exe while my webcam is on and off.