# how to find out which software is using my webcam?

Tags: windows-8

cyberlink youcam is not opening my webcam.it is showing that some other program is using my webcam and i have to close that program first and restart the youcam to get started.and the problem is that I dont know which program is using my webcam.

Comment: have you tried turning the computer off and on again?

Answer (score 0):

Look into below link that might be helpful:

http://lifehacker.com/find-out-what-windows-program-is-using-your-webcam-on-w-1582372561

this might also help you:

[Finding out which app is using the webcam](https://superuser.com/questions/335116/finding-out-which-app-is-using-the-webcam)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.