# Windows 10 Camera App: "Close other apps" Error 0xA00F4243(0xC00D3704)

Tags: windows-10, webcam, logitech-webcam

I recently purchased a Logitech Brio 4k UHD webcam. To test it out, I opened up the Windows Camera app, only to be met with an error message "Close other apps: It looks like another app is using the camera already. 0xA00F4243(0xC00D3704)"

I tried the basic troubleshooting steps such as reinstalling the driver, resetting the Camera app, contacting Logitech, which only resulted in escalating the case.

I also tried [Finding out which app is using the webcam](https://superuser.com/questions/335116/finding-out-which-app-is-using-the-webcam), using Process Explorer to determine which process is accessing the webcam, but Processor Explorer reports 0 processes using the webcam.

The webcam is somewhat functional; Windows Hello works, and the webcam is recognized by Skype, so my guess is that there is a driver compatibility issue with the latest Windows 10 update or something. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score -1):

At this point, please try to scan and repair system:

Run CMD as admin:

dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

SFC /scannow

==========================================

Try steps below:

Methods 1. Run Windows App Troubleshooter

To check if any of Windows apps are damaged, run Windows App Troubleshooter. Click on [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/instantanswers/69e76f90-d54c-44cf-9851-c2d1542790db/run-the-troubleshooter-for-windows-apps) and follow the on-screen instructions.

Method 2. Try a Clean Boot

Click “Windows key” and type msconfig.
Click “System Configuration” and open “Services” tab.
Mark “Hide all Microsoft services” box and select “Disable all.”
Open “Startup” tab and click “Open Task Manager.”
Click on each startup item and select “Disable.”
Close Task Manager and click “OK” on the System Configuration window.
Reboot the system.
If Clean Boot helped to fix 0xA00F4243(0xC00D3704) error, we would recommend you to enable apps one by one. After each enabled app, check if the Camera is working. This way, you will isolate the problematic application.

Method 3. Check privacy settings

Press Windows key + I to open “Settings.”
Go to the “Privacy” category and select the “Camera option.”
Make sure that the “Let apps use my camera” option is turned on.

Method 4: Reinstall the Camera app by running this powershell commands as administrator: 
Refer to this:https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-reinstall-default-apps-in-windows-10/

Comment: I've tried all four methods; none of them worked. I am completely baffled by the lack of support from both Microsoft and Logitech.

Comment: See my [Edit 9-18]