# Webcam bring used by another program (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, webcam

I searched for this topic here and found what looked like a good solution:

[finding out which app is using the webcam](https://superuser.com/questions/335116/finding-out-which-app-is-using-the-webcam)

I went through all the steps, and Process Explorer indicated that CameraHelper.exe was using it. I thought that by killing that process in Task Manager would resolve the issue.

I've been using a Logitech C920 webcam for a few years; it previously worked great.

This week it stopped working on my Dell XPS 9100 running Win 7 Pro 64x. I tried it on two other machines and the camera itself is fine.

It still shows up in Device Manager as working properly. In Sound, it's shown as the default microphone.

I uninstalled and reinstalled the driver.

It's USB, but it's not a USB issue: no matter which port I use it shows up.

When I launch the Logitech software it says:

"We detect your camera is either disconnected or being used by another application, try closing any other application(s) that might be using your camera and then restart Logitech Capture."

Somehow I think a setting in Windows 7 got corrupted and something seems to be blocking access.

I use this to give classes as part of my job, so fixing it is urgent.

Any suggestions of what to check would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [When I had a similar problem it was caused by a third-party OEM USB driver.](https://superuser.com/questions/655117/skype-unable-to-use-webcam).  I am willing to bet you have a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks--I will check this out.

Comment: I ran CamDiag64. Everything appears normal with the camera under "Imaging Devices" (all green check marks)  as well as where it's shown under USB devices. But it's reporting "Unable to start video capture."

Comment: Have you uninstalled any and all Dell software and any Dell USB drivers?

Comment: @Ramhound: The only Dell software I have is their Support Assist. The drivers were all installed when I installed this version of Windows 7. I keep copious notes, and my notes say that I did not install any drivers provided by Dell. What's freaky is that it;s been working consistently fine for a few years and the camera works fine on other systems. Thanks for your input.